# Sniffing HTTP responses from server

Tags: software-recommendation

What software can help what server's http's response on requests? Is there any tool simplier than WireShark?

Comment: Are you trying to sniff on your own communication (e.g. in order to debug something)?  If you are just set up webscarab or any similar proxy,.

Comment: "Paros is for people who need to evaluate the security of their web applications. Through Paros's proxy nature, all HTTP and HTTPS data between server and client, including cookies and form fields, can be intercepted and modified" http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/net/paros

Comment: the logs will show you your server response. Packet sniffing is complex. Personally I prefer tcpdump, but it is not easier then wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

Using `curl` with the -i option will allow you to view the response headers and body from the server. Ex (piped to less for more control over viewing output):

```
curl -i http://askubuntu.com | less
```

The first line of the headers will contain the HTTP status code -- typically something like "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" or "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" -- if that is what you're looking for.

You can use other tools like `head`, `grep`, etc to filter the output if there is a specific line or pattern you are searching for.

Comment: +1 for a solution which does not need extra software.